# Value not getting assigned to Protobuff variable in Python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, mesos, mesosphere

```
message = internal.RegisterExecutorMessage()
message.framework_id.value = self.framework_id
print('message.framework_id.value: %s' % message.framework_id.value)
print('self.framework_id: %s' % self.framework_id)
message.executor_id.value = self.executor_id
print('message.executor_id.value: %s' % message.executor_id.value)
```

Even if the right hand side have proper values, neither message.framework_id.value nor message.executor_id.value getting assigned with these variables.

As a background, trying to write a Mesos Executor in Python on windows...

Comment: Would be helpful to see your protobuf definition, or at least the relevant bits.

Comment: Using https://github.com/wickman/pesos/tree/master/pesos. The definition can be found here, https://github.com/wickman/pesos/tree/master/pesos/vendor/mesos/internal. You can specifically find it in messages_pb2.py